# How does Google Analytics track URL with trailing slash and without?

Tags: google-analytics

Saw in my analytics that the two URLs are tracked separately, one with trailing / and one without /. Is this the case of user inputting the URL without / which is already tracked upon pageload?

Comment: As an aside, Google Analytics has a help page for making "foo/" and "foo/index.html" appear the same.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009675
You could also use GA View Filters for this.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this may be the most plausible reason. This happens if the page can be both with or without *trailing slashes*.
You can fix it with a filter in Google Analytics view that rewrites the URL if it does not contain the trailing slashes.